# import python - no module found error - parent import

Tags: python

I am trying to import a python module from a parent directory running Python 3.8.2 through the CMD but I get a no module found error.

Can anybody help me with that and explain why this happens?

Code explained:
I run this command inside this file `file_inside_child_folder.py`

```
from parent_folder.app import "something inside app.py"
```

and get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parent_folder.app`

Here is my code

```
parent_folder/
            child_folder/
            app.py
                         file_inside_child_folder.py
```

QUESTION:
1: can anybody explain why that happens and how to sort it out?
2: is there anything that prevents importing modules from a parent module to a child module?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is the parent folder on the module search path? Did you add the module  to PYTHONPATH or install it?

Answer (score -1):

You need a `__init__.py` file in your parent folder which tells python that a directory serves as a python module. Also make sure while importing the desired file, you are either running the script from or change the working to the parent folder itself.

Comment: While useful for other reasons, ˋ__init__.pyˋ is not required and does not affect the problem.